# Dropdown (Superfish) menu appears behind Flex Slider in IE 7/8

Tags: html, css, wordpress, drop-down-menu, superfish

The website: http://club16.abcguide.com/

The drop down menu items appear behind the Flex slider in IE 8 for the client, and IE 7 in my compatibility tester.

Help is appreciated in regards to this, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless the `z-index` is explicitly set for positioned elements, IE7/8 will give the positioned element a `z-index` of 0.

Add `position: relative; z-index: 99999;` to `#navigation-wrap` to ensure it has a `z-index` greater than the other elements on the page. This will ensure it stays on top.

Comment: I've added them to the #navigation-wrap div, however they aren't showing up in IE? I'm starting at them in FireFox though.. this is the same issue I had with Danjah's solution..

Comment: I'm not seeing the changes to #navigation-wrap on the site you provided? I added position: relative; z-index: 99999; via IE DEV tools as an inline style and verified that it works in IE7/8

Comment: Disregard my last comment, it's working now. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 2):

`.flexslider` has `position:relative;` but no `z-index` CSS property, if you add `z-index:1` to that container, and then `position:relative;` and `z-index:2;` to any one of your suckerfish menu containers (I added it to `ul.menu` in IE debug tools), the menu will then be positioned atop the slider.

Comment: I've added the CSS to '.flexslider' and 'ul.menu'.. however, the CSS doesn't seem to be appearing in IE? It's working in Firefox though..

Comment: The CSS for 'ul.menu' isn't appearing*

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, if you have a CSS gradient on your navigation, early versions of IE will have trouble with drop downs.